# Issue with Erlang, passing variables to two other functions

Tags: erlang

Hello I am trying to create a program that has a function `main_function()` that holds two int variables and then passes the variables to two other functions `difference()` and `sum()`.  I want the two functions perform the computation and display the results.  In turn calling each of the two functions from the `main_function()`.  However I am currently having an issue with my program only outputting the bottom most function that is being called in the `main_function()`

Here is what I have

```
-module(numbers).
-export([main_function/2]).


main_function(X,Y)->
   sum(X,Y),
   difference(X,Y).

sum(X,Y)->
   X + Y.

difference(X,Y)->
   X - Y.
```

My output for this would be 2 if I was to pass 5 and 3 would for X and Y respectively and my program seems to be only using the `difference()` function and not `sum()`.  I am looking for an output of 8 and 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change main_function/2 like below

```
main_function(X,Y)->
A = sum(X,Y),
B = difference(X,Y),
{A, B}.
```

The result in shell when X = 5, Y = 3 is:

```
{8, 2}
```

Or like this

```
main_function(X,Y)->
A = sum(X,Y),
B = difference(X,Y),
io:format("A = ~p~nB = ~p~n", [A, B]).
```

The result in shell when X = 5, Y = 3 is:

```
A = 8
B = 2
```